# If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree three leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $(x−1)^2$ and leaves remainder $–1$ when divided by $(x+1)^2$

Tags: polynomials

> $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree three which leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $(x−1)^2$ and leaves remainder $–1$ when divided by $(x+1)^2$.
>
> If $f(x)=0$ has roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, then $$(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)=\text?$$

The answer to the question is $-3$. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? How can you write $f(x)$ when you know that the remainder is $1$ when divided by $(x-1)^2$?

Comment: Also note that the roots being $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ means that $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$

Comment: Use Vieta's formulae for $\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f\!+\!1\bmod{(x\!+\!1)^2(x\!-\!1)^2} = (x\!+\!1)^2\left[\dfrac{\smash{\overbrace{f\!+\!1}^{\textstyle{\color{#c00}1\!+\!1}}}}{(x\!+\!1)^2}\,\bmod{(x\!-\!1)^2}\right]$ $=\, (x\!+\!1)^2\left[\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{2\!-\!x}}{2}\right]$

by, with $t=x\!-\!1,\,$ we have: $ \bmod t^2\!:\,\ \dfrac{4}{(x\!+\!1)^2} = \dfrac{4}{(2\!+\!t)^2} =\dfrac{1}{1\!+\!t} = 1\!-\!t = \color{#0a0}{2\!-\!x}$

Comment: We applied  HF mod HG = H(F mod G) =  [$\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) in the first line. $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P'(x)$ has roots $1,-1$. Hence $P'(x) = a(x-1)(x+1) =a (x^2-1)$

and hence $P(x) = a \left(\dfrac{x^3}{3} -x\right)+b$. Using $P(1)=1, P(-1)=-1$, we get $b=0, a=-\dfrac{3}{2}$

Hence $P(x) =\dfrac{x^3-3x}{2}$. It is easy to see that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \alpha \beta= -3$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Your first assumption says that $(f-1)(1)=(f-1)'(1)=0$ since $f-1$ is divisible by $(X-1)^2,$ and your second assumption says that $ (f+1)(-1)=(f+1)'(-1)=0$ since $f+1$ is divisible by $(X+1)$^2.

You then get a linear system that you can solve to finally find $f$. Then apply roots-coefficients relations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see how to write explicit polynomial equations, i.e.,
$$
f(x)=(ax+b)(x-1)^2+1=(cx+d)(x+1)^2-1
$$
Comparison of the $4$ coefficients of the two cubic polynomials gives you $4$ linear equations in $a,b,c,d$ with a unique solution. The resulting cubic polynomial $f$ is very easy and has only two terms.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Let $f(x)=1+(x-1)^2(ax+b)=-1+(x+1)^2(cx+d)$

$ax^3+x^2(b-2a)+x(a-2b)+b-1=cx^3+x^2(d+2c)+x(c+2d)+d+1$

Now compare the coefficients of the different exponent of $x$

$\implies c=a$

$b-1=d+1\iff d=b-2$

$b-2a=d+2c\iff b=d+2(c+a)=d+4a$

$a-2b=c+2d\implies b=-d=2-b$

Hope you can take it from here?