# Find a polynomial of degree at most 7 which leaves remainders –1 and 1 upon division by $(x-1)^4$ and $(x+1)^4$ respectively

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> A polynomial of degree at most 7 is such that leaves remainders –1 and 1 upon division by $(x-1)^4$ and $(x+1)^4$ respectively. Find the sum of roots of this polynomial.

Now as we have to find sum , I thinks it's pointing towards using viete. From remainder theorem , we get $f(x) = g_1(x)(x-1)^4-1$ and $f(x) = g_2(x)(x+1)^4+1$ where $g_{1,2}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree atmost 3 . But from this point , I get no more ideas. Like assuming a cubic for g(x) and then using binomial on $(x-1)^4$ is to too long and doesn't get me anywhere. Please help

The above approach is followed [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553919/if-fx-is-a-polynomial-of-degree-three-leaves-remainder-1-when-divided-by) but there it's manageable because the powers are small, so is there no alternate elegant way ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $f(x) = g_1(x)(x-1)^4-1$ we get $f'(x)=(g_1'(x)(x-1)+4g_1(x))(x-1)^3$, and so 
$$f'(x)=g(x)(x-1)^3$$ 
for some polynomial $g(x)$. Similary from the $f(x) = g_2(x)(x+1)^4+1$ we obtain 
$$f'(x)=h(x)(x+1)^3$$ for some polynomial $h(x)$.

Having $f(x)$ seventh degree polynomial, that makes $f'(x)$ a sixth degree polynomial, and so we have 
$$f'(x)=K(x-1)^3(x+1)^3=K(x^6-3x^4+3x^2-1)$$
for some $K \in \mathbb{Q}$. So, by integrating, 
$$
f(x)=K\left(\frac{1}{7}x^7-\frac{3}{5}x^5+x^3-x\right)+L,
$$
for some $K,L \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Finally, by Vieta's formula, sum of the roots of $f(x)$ is just $0$.

Note that it is also straightforward to derive the constants by using $f(1)=-1$ and $f(-1)=1$, however for finding the sum of roots, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

We want that
$$\bigl[f(x)):=\bigr]\qquad a(x)(x-1)^4-1 =b(x)(x+1)^4+1$$
for certain polynomials
$$a(x)=\sum_{k=0}^3a_k x^k,\quad b(x)=\sum_{k=0}^3b_k x^k\ .$$
Put the coefficients of the degree $7$ polynomial $$\phi(x):=\bigl(a(x)(x-1)^4-1\bigr)-\bigl(b(x)(x+1)^4+1\bigr)$$
to $0$. This determines the $a_k$ and the $b_k$. You obtain
$$a(x)=1+{29x\over16}+{5x^2\over4}+{5x^3\over16},\qquad b(x)=-a(-x)\ .$$ This leads to the unique solution of your problem, namely
$$f(x)=a(x)(x-1)^4-1={x\over16}(-35+35x^2-21x^4+5x^6)\ .$$